# Multiple sheets in same csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wanted to create multiple sheets in the same CSV file

```
   a='Portfolio 1' 
   file_name = f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}{type}'
    with open(file_name, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Name of Fund','Amount of Units','Price','Date']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
```

Currently, one CSV file in the name of Portfolio 1 gets created with the list of names present in field names as column headers, I wanted to name that sheet as Mutual Fund, and with the same column headers create multiple sheets with the name of stocks, SIP, Bonds/PPF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have 2 sheets in 1 **CSV**. That's the way CSV's (or 'flat-files') are created.

You can, however, create 2 sheets in 1 **XLSX** - the newer Excel format.

**Python Modules to write to XLSX**

- [XLSXWriter (Python)](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/)
- [Openpyxl (my favourite)](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

As Anthony has said, you cannot create a CSV with multiple sheets, you can however do this with excel and pandas:

assuming you've declared your variables above.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}{type}')

# columns/fields to use? 
fieldnames = ['Name of Fund','Amount of Units','Price','Date']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('your_new_file.xlsx')

for col in fieldnames:
    # assuming your behavior here replace with desired result. 
    df[col].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=col)
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert multiple sheets excel to multiple csv files **not multiple sheet csv files**. `xlrd` in python is very useful for read excel files sheet by sheet